# Uncaught Error: Class "B" not found. This error giving while using __toString method in php

Tags: php, class, oop, php-8, php-8.1

Giving error while this code applied
**Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "B" not found in D:\laragon\www\test2\collect.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\laragon\www\test2\collect.php on line 6**

```
$b = new B;

echo $b;

class B{

    public $a;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->a = "NEW VALUE";
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }
}
```

No Error in giving if __toString() method removed

php version: 8.1

Please helper me to understand why this error giving.

Comment: Define `class B{}`  at first and then call `$b = new B;`

Comment: Class B should implement Stringable, just for completeness.

Comment: Swap out the line where you echo $b with a line that does a var_dump of $b, what do you get from the var_dump?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam The interesting question here is why the mere existence of a `__toString()` method makes the `new` call succeed or fail: https://3v4l.org/9DmFi

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I didn't see any errors in the code except the calling https://3v4l.org/DLgR2. Failed output https://3v4l.org/pPB9X . (check the both error  messages)